# Symfony 2.5 "You have requested a non-existent service "siteTest.b"

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

When run workspace/app_dev.php, no problem. But when I try to run workspace/app.php I get:

> "You have requested a non-existent service "siteTest.b"

I dont have the first clue what am I doing wrong.

**app/config/config.yml :**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
framework:
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

**src/Site/TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:**

```
parameters:
    siteTest.aa: Site\TestBundle\Controller\a

services:
    siteTest.b:
        class: %siteTest.aa%
```

**src/Site/TestBundle/DependencyInjection/SiteTestExtension.php :**

```
namespace Site\TestBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
class SiteTestExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

**src/Site/TestBundle/Controller/a.php :**

```
namespace Site\TestBundle\Controller;
class a {
    public function printTest() {
        var_dump('Test');
        exit;
    }
}
```

**src/Site/TestBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:**

```
namespace Site\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $aaa = $this->get('siteTest.b');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: clear your `prod` cache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

run command `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` to clear your `prod` cache

Answer (score 13):

you might also need to add the code below inside

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: '@TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml' }
```

alternatively you can use the cookbook configurations http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class

Comment: Thanks, I did not know how to import the configuration only one file in particular.