# Non-existing service in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a class that I'd like to use as a service:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;

class Functions
{


private $em;

public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * Init the add Event to Eventlog function
 *
 * @param string $text Text to save
 * @param User $user
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function addEvent($text, User $user)
{

    $event = new Event();
    $event->setUser($user);
    $event->setText($text);
    $event->setEventTimestamp(new \DateTime());
    $this->em->persist($event);

    try{
        $this->em->flush();
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

I inject the service via `services.yml` like this:

```
services:
    app.ccrm:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\Functions
        calls:
            - [setEntityManager, ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
```

and make the call with this in my controller:

`$this->get('app.ccrm')->addEvent('Event IDXXX',$this->getUser());`

No it gives me the

> You have requested a non-existent service "app.ccrm".

Things I did:

- `php bin/console cache:clear`
- `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
- Manually delete `dev` and `prod` in `var/cache`
- Use different browser
- read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683041/symfony-3-you-have-requested-a-non-existent-service-is-driving-me-crazy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919496/symfony-2-5-you-have-requested-a-non-existent-service-sitetest-b)
- ran `php bin/console debug:container app.ccrm` which resulted in:

  `Service ID       app.ccrm
  Class            AppBundle\Entity\Functions
  Tags             -
  Calls            setEntityManager
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes`

Now I am all out of ideas! Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the output of `php bin/console debug:container app.ccrm` again, and look at the `public: no` line. You need to set your service to be public.

```
services:
    app.ccrm:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\Functions
        public: true
        calls:
            - [setEntityManager, ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
```

Additionally, check the [documentation about default service visibility](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#container-public)

Comment: simple as that! Thank you